# Can I embed a paypal link/ button into an email? It will be for people to pay me

Tags: email, paypal

Any help appreciated - want to be able to send info and payment options in an email

Comment: Show your work please?

Comment: Can people stop acting like gays and explain to new comers nicely how stackoverflow works instead of down voting them?

Comment: To answer the questions - there was no option given when I created the buttons to integrate them into email just html code.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.x.com/developers/community/blogs/ppintegrationsnate/put-paypal-button-link-email-outlook

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Adam - only option that came up when I generatie the button was for HTML